# how to access master page control from content page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind

I have a master page which contains a label for status messages. I need to set the status text from different .aspx pages.  How can this be done from the content page?

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string StatusNachricht
    {
        get
        {
            return lblStatus.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblStatus.Text = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

    }
}
```

I have tried this, but was unsuccessful in making it work:

```
public partial class DatenAendern : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    var master = Master as Site;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        if (master != null)
        {
            master.setStatusLabel("");
        }
    }        

    protected void grdBenutzer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {           
            try
            {
                //some code

                if (master != null)
                {
                    master.setStatusLabel("Passwort erfolgreich geändert.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (master != null)
                {
                    master.setStatusLabel("Passwort konnte nicht geändert werden!");
                }                                       
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: so u want to access the `label's text property` in all your `aspx` pages....right?

Comment: yes that's basically what i'm trying to achieve...

Comment: @LeonidasFett: Should work, so what problem do you have? Have you used the debugger?

Comment: i get an error that for var the namespace is not available even though it works when i use it inside a method. and it tells me that Master does not have an object reference...

Comment: Ah, you cannot initialize the field in this way. Use `Page_Init` to intialize it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In the MasterPage.cs file add the `property` of `Label` like this:

```
public string ErrorMessage
{
    get
    {
        return lblMessage.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        lblMessage.Text = value;
    }
}
```

On your `aspx` page, just below the Page Directive add this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Master Path Name"..... %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="Master Path Name" %>   // Add this
```

And in your `codebehind(aspx.cs)` page you can then easily access the `Label Property` and set its `text` as required. Like this:

```
this.Master.ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message here";
```

Comment: change the title of this question to more relevant one. 'how to access master page control from content page'

Comment: ok now i get a NullReferenceException for the label in the property field...i uploaded my new code above. did i miss something here?

Comment: seems like u missed the initialization part that Tim has mentioned below.

Comment: hi dear friend this not work on update panel , how can i run this by update panel

Comment: you need to call Update method on your updatePanel. If you want to push your changes from the code behind to updatepanel directly. Did work for me.

Comment: If you don't want to add the <%@ MasterType %> line to your aspx, it will also work if you cast the master page to its type in codebehind like so:
`((YourMasterPageType)Master).ErrorMessage = "Message";`

Answer (score 35):

In Content page you can access the label and set the text such as

Here 'lblStatus' is the your master page label ID

```
Label lblMasterStatus = (Label)Master.FindControl("lblStatus");

lblMasterStatus.Text  = "Meaasage from content page";
```

Comment: And if the master has a master, you have to to `Master.Master`.

Answer (score 10):

It Works

To find master page controls on Child page

```
Label lbl_UserName = this.Master.FindControl("lbl_UserName") as Label;                    
lbl_UserName.Text = txtUsr.Text;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a helper method for this in my System.Web.UI.Page class

```
protected T FindControlFromMaster<T>(string name) where T : Control
{
     MasterPage master = this.Master;
     while (master != null)
     {
         T control = master.FindControl(name) as T;
         if (control != null)
             return control;

         master = master.Master;
     }
     return null;
}
```

then you can access using below code.

```
Label lblStatus = FindControlFromMaster<Label>("lblStatus");
if(lblStatus!=null) 
    lblStatus.Text = "something";
```

Answer (score 3):

You [**cannot use `var` in a field**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx), only on  local variables.

But even this won't work:

```
Site master = Master as Site;
```

Because you cannot use `this` in a field and `Master as Site` is the same as `this.Master as Site`. So just initialize the field from `Page_Init` when the page is fully initialized and you can use `this`:

```
Site master = null;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    master = this.Master as Site;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated if you have a nested MasterPage. You need to first find the content control that contains the nested MasterPage, and then find the control on your nested MasterPage from that.

Crucial bit: **Master.Master**.

See here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1059255.aspx?Nested+master+pages+and+Master+FindControl

Example:

> 'Find the content control
>
> Dim ct As ContentPlaceHolder = Me.Master.Master.FindControl("cphMain")
>
> 'now find controls inside that content
>
> Dim lbtnSave As LinkButton = ct.FindControl("lbtnSave")

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access an  html element: this is an HTML Anchor...

My nav bar has items that are not list items (`<li>`) but rather html anchors (`<a>`)

See below: (This is the site master)

```
<nav class="mdl-navigation">
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="" runat="server" id="liHome">Home</a>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="" runat="server" id="liDashboard">Dashboard</a>
</nav>
```

Now in your code behind for another page, for mine, it's the login page...

On PageLoad() define this:

```
HtmlAnchor lblMasterStatus = (HtmlAnchor)Master.FindControl("liHome");
lblMasterStatus.Visible =false;

HtmlAnchor lblMasterStatus1 = (HtmlAnchor)Master.FindControl("liDashboard");
lblMasterStatus1.Visible = false;
```

Now we have accessed the site masters controls, and have made them invisible on the login page.