# How to hide a div which is in master page using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Iam tried to hide a div which is placed in master page,but i got an error like this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

My codes

```
<div runat="server" id="cnms">
 <a href="Cinemas.aspx">Cinemas</a>
</div>

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        AdminMaster admns = new AdminMaster();//This si my admin page
        admns.FindControl("cnms").Visible = false;//I got error here
     }
 }
```

What went wrong for me?any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you are using is instantiating a new instance of the masterpage, which when you do that it all of the control references are null.  You need to use the existing master page instance, using the `Page.Master` property like the following:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    AdminMaster admns = (AdminMaster)Page.Master; //This si my admin page
    admns.FindControl("cnms").Visible = false;//I got error here
 }
```