# ASP.NET How do i access a control that's in a master page, FROM Another class (in another page)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using Visual Basic. I have a label in the master page. From the click of a button (that's on another page), I want to write code that will change the text property of this label in the master page.

I have a master page called Site.Master and all I want to do is something like:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Me.Master.Page.Label.Text = "new text" 'Of course this NOT right.
End Sub
```

(What I've placed inside there is just pseudo code.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access master page control from content page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page)

Comment: I don't get the "that's on another page" part. Are you trying to change the value from different pages? You could add a method in your master page and call it. CType(Me.Page.Master, MasterPageClass).ChangeLabel("new text")

Comment: @THE_LOTUS Thanks man. It worked

Answer (score 0):

in C#

```
((Label)this.Page.Master.FindControl("yourLable")).Text = "new text";
```