# li Control from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i can't access to a li control in my master page,
i need to set it visible = false when user isn't "admin", with runat = "server" i can't access from code, why?  how can i solve this problem?
aspx

```
<li runat="server" id="tabadmin"><a runat="server" href="~/DatiInterni.aspx" >Amministrazione sito</a></li>
```

aspx.cs

```
if (Context.User.Identity.Name != "admin")
{
    HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl) FindControl("tabadmin");
    li.Attributes.Add("Visible", "false");

}
```

login view

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">   
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login" title="Login">Accedi</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register" title="Register">Registrati</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
     <%--Lato destro della navbar se l'utente si è autenticato--%>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  runat="server">
         <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Ciao, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
      <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" runat="server" id="menu">
        <li><a href="/Apparati.aspx">Dati clienti</a></li>
        <li><a href="/DatiInterni.aspx">Dati interni</a></li>
     <li runat="server" id="tabadmin"><a runat="server" href="~/DatiInterni.aspx" >Amministrazione sito</a></li>
     <li>
        <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Disconnetti" LogoutPageUrl="/Account/Login.aspx" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
    </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: li after FindControl is null

Comment: If the control is on the master page and you want to access it from a content page then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page

Comment: @emanuele: where is this `li`? Is it nested in another control?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i'll post the entire code in answers

Comment: @Steve i want to access it from master and control is in master

Comment: Does the proposed duplicate solve this issue?

Comment: @TimSchmelter no it doesn't

Comment: @Emanuele: so you have tried to give the `LoginView` an `Id` and then used: `HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl) loginView1.FindControl("tabadmin")` (note difference: you use `this.FindControl` and here i use `loginView1.FindControl`). `Control.FindControl` is not searching for this control recursively through child controls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter even with loginview1.Findcontrol it's not working

Comment: @TimSchmelter solved, solution in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this code

```
            <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ID="LogSection">


                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login" title="Login">Accedi</a></li>
                      <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register" title="Register">Registrati</a></li>  
                    </ul>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                 <%--Lato destro della navbar se l'utente si è autenticato--%>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"  runat="server">
                     <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Ciao, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> </a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" id="menu" runat="server">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" runat="server" id="list" >
                    <li><a href="/Apparati.aspx">Dati clienti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/DatiInterni.aspx">Dati interni</a></li>
                 <li runat="server" id="tabadmin" visible="true"><a runat="server" href="~/Admin/Administration.aspx" >Amministrazione sito</a></li>
                                                    <li>
                            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Disconnetti" LogoutPageUrl="/Account/Login.aspx" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                        </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                    </ul>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

code behind

```
    if (Context.User.Identity.Name != "admin" && Context.User.Identity.Name != "")
    {
        HtmlGenericControl menu = (HtmlGenericControl)LogSection.FindControl("menu");
        HtmlGenericControl list = (HtmlGenericControl)menu.FindControl("list");
        HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)list.FindControl("tabadmin");
        li.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't post the code in the answer like this! If you want to add something, you need to edit your question.

Comment: But i'm fairly sure that you don't need the `list` to find the `li`, the `NamingContainer` of it is the `LogSection`, so it should work already if you use `(HtmlGenericControl)LogSection.FindControl("tabadmin")`

Comment: @TimSchmelter i've tried with only (HtmlGenericControl)LogSection.FindControl("tabadmin") but it didn't work, with menu and list it works