# From aspx.cs call ASP.NET Master Page (.Master) function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

In the ASP.NET Master Page (.Master) there is a text-box that should filter the content in a website. To do it I would like to call the function GetMessageLogs in the .aspx.cs file.

> Site.Master:

```
<button onclick="containCatText()" class="catbtn">Category</button>
<div id="myDropdownCat" class="catdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myCat" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
</div>
<script>
    var myCat = document.getElementById("myCat").value;
</script>
```

> Feeds.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Feeds.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportTool.Users.Feeds" %>
```

> Feeds.aspx.cs:

```
namespace ReportTool.Users
{
    public partial class Feeds : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Inov.ReportTool rt = new Inov.ReportTool();    
        MessageLogs = rt.GetMessageLogs(null, Server.MapPath("/ReportTool/Photo") + "\\", Server.MapPath("/ReportTool/Video") + "\\", new DateTime(2016, 09, 15),DateTime.Now, "%J%","Tr");
```

My question is simply how do I replace the "%J%" in the Feeds.aspx.cs from the variable myCat from Site.Maste?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use ASP.Net WebForms:**

First, data in the `myCat` control can't be easily sent to a code-behind (.aspx.cs) page because `myCat` doesn't have the `runat="server"` property.

Additionally, WebForms is (typically) set up to have each page operate independently. There are ways around this (calling functions from your Site.Master code-behind page, using Session variables, using a database - these all involve creating a communication channel between the two pages you're using).

In my experience, it's much easier if the Master page had the search function in its code-behind.

**If you want to use JavaScript instead**

Since you have references to JavaScript functions, you may feel more comfortable following this path (or not - there isn't really a right answer here): if you want to use JavaScript and keep the search function were in a web API, Microsoft has a really in-depth walkthrough available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have to restructure the whole project. Is there anything more direct?

Comment: You can reference data on a master page from a "child" page, but it's (in my opinion) a lot more complicated and error-prone. I'd suggest reading over this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page) if you're interested in that.