# How to find a master page list control using its id on master page iitself and add attribute to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, findcontrol

I'm trying to add href attribute to list controls in master page in the page load function based on the type of person logged in the website.

1.first step is to make a call to database to get name of the form,module of the form(i.e, in which category it belongs), and control id to which form gets added, this result i'm storing in list.

```
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(dr["FormName"].ToString(), dr["ModuleName"].ToString(), dr["controlid"].ToString()));
```

2.now i want to find the control in master page which i have received from the database. and add href attributes to only those id's.

```
  foreach(var v in list)
  {
   var cont= Page.FindControl(v.Item3);
   cont.Attributes.Add("href", "~/" + v.Item2 + "/" + v.Item1);
  }
```

but its not working i don't know how to achieve it.
neither i'm able to find the control nor it i can add attributes to it because
cont.Attributes.add is not a method.

my aspx code:

```
                           <li id="liCRM" runat="server" class="dropdown full-length">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CRM</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">

                                <ul>
                                    <li class="custom-header text-capitalize">          
                                     <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>CRM</a></li>
                                <li class="topmenu"><a id="CRM1" runat="server">Leads / Enquiries</a></li>
                                <li class="topmenu"><a id="CRM2" runat="server">Tasks / Works</a></li>
```

i have already tried this :

```
 HtmlAnchor ct = (HtmlAnchor)Page.FindControl(v.Item3);
                        ct.Attributes.Add("href","~/" + v.Item2.Substring(4) + "/" + v.Item1);
```

ct is always null. :(
please help

Comment: instead of marking as duplicate please try to help people.

Comment: did you try the answers from the duplicate question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573505/how-to-access-master-page-control-from-content-page

Comment: i tried that ..i found control by this--> Control mycontrol=FindControl(v.Item1)..but now i want to add href attribute to this control (mycontrol)

Comment: please help any one

Comment: try  HtmlAnchor ct = (HtmlAnchor)Page.Master.FindControl(v.Item3);   ct.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Test.aspx");
Even though you are in Masterpage code behind, the way masterpage works,  you still have to use Page.Master.Findcontrol to find it.

Comment: thank you @imAbhi thank you so much im new to asp.net..this is working